# Resize the contour/ Correcting patchy contour OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am finding the contours, making a mask of them, then cropping that part from the original image and applying face detection on that. However the contour is coming out patchy with only a part of my face in the mask. Hence the cropped out image is not able to do proper image detection.

```
Mat FindAndDrawContours(Mat& image, Mat& originalImage)
    {
        vector<vector<Point>> contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        findContours(image, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
         Mat drawing(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
             drawContours(drawing, contours, (int)i, Scalar(0, 0, 0), FILLED, LINE_8, hierarchy, 0);
        }

        Mat crop(image.rows, image.cols, CV_8UC3);
        crop.setTo(Scalar(0, 0, 0));
        originalImage.copyTo(crop, drawing);
        normalize(drawing.clone(), drawing, 0.0, 255.0, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC3);

         imshow("Test", crop);

        return crop;
    }
```

I need to resize to fix that patchy contour.

[image: Run-time image]

Comment: Is your expectation finding the contours of your face and getting a reference for face detection? Why dont u use ur image as reference to face detection directly? And what do u mean by saying "resize to fix patchy"?

Comment: It would be helpful to have your original image too